Are these typos in n-step tree backup section in Sutton-Barto?
Sutton-Barto, page 153.

It seems to me that the "red" underlined parts are typos.
1-) 2-step tree backup return formula is valid for $t<T-2$ but the n-step version which includes $n\ge 2$ is valid for $t<T-1$.
2-) Also, should $G_{T-1:t+n}=R_T$ not be $G_{T-1:T-1+n}=R_T$?
